# Optimising backtracking in regex

Tags: .net, regex

There is a number of web links on the page I am parsing, I want to capture all *h3* links except those with a specific sub-elements in them.

Example page:

```
<h3 class="r">
    <a href="http://Capture This"></a>
</h3>
   <some tags here>
   <more tags  here>
   <a bit more tags here>
   </div>
</div>
<h3 class="r">
   <a href="http://Capture This"></a>
</h3>
<some tags here>
  <class=ml>
  <more tags here>
  <class=tcl>
  <a bit more tags here>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="r">
  <a href="http://Dont capture this"></a>
</h3>
  <some tags here>
  <class=ml>
  <more tags here>
  <a bit more tags here>
  </div>
</div>
```

Capture h3 links:

- Which do not contain *class=ml* sub-element
- Or contain class ml and *class=tcl* elements

This regex matches all *h3* links:

```
h3 class=["']?[^"']+["']?><a href=["']?(https?://[^"']+)["']?
```

This regex matches all *h3* links without *class=ml* in their sub-elements (each *h3* element is separated with doulbe /div tag):

```
h3 class=["']?r["']?><a href=["']?(https?://[^"']+)["']?(?=((?!class=ml).)*(</div>){2,})
```

Finally, regex that I am looking for captures all *h3* links, which do not contain *class=ml*, or
contain both *class=ml* and *class=tcl* in their sub-elements (in this order)

```
h3 class=["']?[^"']+["']?><a href=["']?(https?://[^"']+)["']?(?=((?!class=ml)(?!(</div>){2,}).)*(class=ml((?!class=tcl>).)*class=tcl>|(</div>){2,}))
```

Regex, which I came with, works, but very inefficiently due to backtracking. For example 100 iterations of standard page matching take 50 seconds to complete. Is there any way to improve this regex, so it wouldn't backtrack that much?

I believe I start to understand what HTML parsing [Cthulhu way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) actually is, but hopefully it won't disturb *anyone's* sleep.

P.S. I am on.NET regex engine, if that influences my options.

Comment: I would recommend to simply get a list of all the h3 links and the class attributes of their inner tags and then you can filter them to get your desired result.

Comment: Good suggestion, and is most logical. However, I am restricted with using only regex.

Comment: Throw away your regular expressions and download the HTML Agility Pack. Life is way too short to try any kind of serious HTML parsing with regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are restricted to using regex only, but that's not a great choice for parsing HTML. You can easily traverse the DOM with .net, which is much less complicated and will perform much better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/213550